# Capture an url ending with a slash with Lumen's router

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing, lumen, lumen-5.2

I have a Lumen project (Lumen 5.2) and I need to do two different things for two identical urls except for an ending slash '/'. For example:

```
http://example.com/some/path   --> Show a resource named 'path'
http://example.com/some/path/  --> List the content of the 'path' folder
```

But I didn't found a way to write routes able to capture such difference.

I tried with this:

```
$app->get('/{p:.*}', function ($p) use ($app) {
  return 'Case 1: ' . $p;
});

$app->get('/{p:.*}/', function ($p) use ($app) {
  return 'Case 2: ' . $p;
});
```

But both urls (`/some/path` and `/some/path/`) are captured by the last route and `$p` is `some/path` in both cases, so I can't know what url it was.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to capture it in the same route then inside the closure detecting if there is a trailing slash?

Comment: Just a hunch...try defining the route with the trailing slash first. Probably won't do it but worth a shot.

Comment: @ddelnano yes, I tried with only this route: `'/{p:.*}'`, but with or without the trailing slash in the url, the parameter `$p` is always `some/path` (without the slash)...

Comment: @BenHarold hehe :).. yes, I tried to put the second route as first! But sadly the result is almost the same: for any url the last defined route will catch it and the parameter `$p` doesn't have the trailing slash (`$p` is always `some/path`)... :(

Comment: The .htaccess file Laravel ships with will redirect if there is a trailing slash to the non-trailing slash version.

Comment: @user3158900 So, is there no way to get the trailing slash version inside the router?